# Need help with forwarding a port of a local service through VPN so it can be accessed from the net

Tags: ubuntu, networking, arch-linux, port-forwarding, wireguard

TL;DR:
Goal: to forward a service on a local machine with its associated ports under a VPN to the VPS so it can be accessible from the net, checked port to be open with a port checker.

I think that the ports are not showed as open and the program not running correctly is because the ports are somehow still stuck locally. Even with the ports opened in both firewalls it is still not being forwarded to the VPS under a wireguard connection.

Context in full:

I need some help of linux vets on this problem. I run a program, Airdcpp web client on my local machine. And there are three ports that it uses, for this case I will use a random three of them: `22000`, `22001`, `22002` as an example.

I then allow these three ports with my firewall program `firewalld`'s GUI. So in and out traffic will be allowed. Afterwards I go into my router's settings page and then forward those three ports to my computer's local IP address. Eg. 22000-22000 --> 192.168.1.104. At that point, if I use a port checker like this one: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, it shows it being open and the program runs as it should.

But the problem with this is my home IP is exposed so I would like to mask it, there are two ways that I am exploring. Using a proxy or VPN.

In the case of a proxy, transferring of data will be limited no matter what I try to set up because of the program's innate limitations. So VPN leaves itself to be my only option.

So I have set up wireguard using this script: https://github.com/angristan/wireguard-install on my Linode VPS. In which case I believe is directly exposed to the internet, so all I did was `ufw allow` the above three ports and then `wg-quick up wg0` on my local machine. Then VPN connected, the program runs and IP is changed. Problem is, ports are still showed to be closed when I use the port checker and of course, the program is not running under optimal conditions.

At this point I have all the ports set to be allowed on VPS and local machine. VPS connected normally. I run a program on the VPS also, using another port, and I can still access that normally while I am using it as a wireguard server, showing that the VPS is exposed directly to the net and Linode is not blocking anything especially since those three ports aren't special, like per say for emails.

So I conjectured that in order for my local service to appear as connectable and opened in a VPN connection, I will need to "forward" (I do not know of the actual technical term) three of them through the VPN protocol somehow so it will appear as if the program is running on the VPS and I can access it with a port checker, under the VPS's IP and port associated.
Though at this point is when I have no idea what to do, and I need some help from seniors out there for any ideas. Thank you for reading! Any comments of ideas to help or a pointing to a guide or a mistake in my thoughts are welcomed!

Technical info:

```
local machine OS: Arch Linux
program name: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/airdcpp-webclient/
VPS: Linode ubuntu  20.04.1 LTS, running wireguard with a ufw firewall
```

EDIT:
wireguard configs

VPS side:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 49503
PrivateKey = 
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

### Client local_arch
[Peer]
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
```

I think those are internal IPs so they are okay to be shared? Please correct if I am wrong.

local machine config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey = 
Endpoint = <linode.IP>:49503
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
```

Comment: This might help you: https://george.czabania.com/2019_03_18/

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, thanks for the article, looked through it and came out with a more accurate post about the problem here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652403/forwarding-the-local-service-ports-through-wireguard-and-back-for-the-local-serv

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing!